# What type of encoding is this? I am told it's Bencode, but it doesn't look standard

Tags: encoding, encode

I'm working on a project in which they have stored the following type of encoded data in a BLOB type column of a mysql database. I've asked around and have been told this is Bencode, however, from what I'm seeing online it doesn't appear to be standard Bencode.

**Wiki for Bencode**

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bencode

**Example of encoded data**

```
a:11:{i:0;a:3:{s:11:"question_id";s:2:"46";s:6:"answer";s:1:"2";s:7:"correct";b:1;}i:1;a:3:{s:11:"question_id";s:2:"45";s:6:"answer";s:1:"2";s:7:"correct";b:0;}i:2;a:3:{s:11:"question_id";s:2:"44";s:6:"answer";s:1:"2";s:7:"correct";b:0;}i:3;a:3:{s:11:"question_id";s:2:"43";s:6:"answer";s:1:"1";s:7:"correct";b:0;}i:4;a:3:{s:11:"question_id";s:2:"42";s:6:"answer";s:1:"3";s:7:"correct";b:0;}i:5;a:3:{s:11:"question_id";s:2:"41";s:6:"answer";s:1:"2";s:7:"correct";b:0;}i:6;a:3:{s:11:"question_id";s:2:"40";s:6:"answer";s:1:"0";s:7:"correct";b:1;}i:7;a:3:{s:11:"question_id";s:2:"39";s:6:"answer";s:1:"0";s:7:"correct";b:0;}i:8;a:3:{s:11:"question_id";s:2:"38";s:6:"answer";s:1:"1";s:7:"correct";b:1;}i:9;a:3:{s:11:"question_id";s:2:"37";s:6:"answer";s:1:"3";s:7:"correct";b:0;}i:10;a:3:{s:11:"question_id";s:2:"36";s:6:"answer";s:1:"2";s:7:"correct";b:1;}}
```

**What I've noticed so far**

I've noticed that the encoding describes different types of data using letters and integers similar to Bencode.

Example:
`s:11:"question_id";`

I'm assuming `s` stands for 'string', and that `11` is defining the length of the string `question_id`. Also, it would appear that the beginning of the data (`a:11:`) describes an array with a length of 11. While this is similar to standard Bencode, it doesn't seem to use the standard syntax that Bencode uses.

Does anyone have any ideas what type of encoding this is? Is this a non-standard Bencode format, or something entirely different? I'm looking for a parser in PHP or Python, and having a name for the encoding would definitely help in my search.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the PHP serialization format, unserializable using [`unserialize`](http://php.net/unserialize).
See http://codepad.org/l7Z9cITo.

Comment: Thanks very much, deceze! I've been stuck on this for a couple of days now. Even better that it's a PHP format and is easily decoded.